# WinForm scroll option

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scroll

I have completed a basic Form but for some reason I cant fit everything in screen even though I extended it in designer.

I decided to complete a scroll bar to assist with this but even with the scroll bar, the form stays one place.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems odd behavior.  Do you have any specific sizing code?  Have you set things like the max/min sizes of the form in the designer

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot ?